# Powershell Get-Process and Task Manager discrepancy

Tags: powershell

I'm making a PowerShell script to get the top 10 process that are consuming memory, based on the Get-Process's value Working Set (WS). I'm running the following line and getting the results, looks great, but when I check in task manager I don't get the same values. Even the order is different.

```
Get-Process | Sort WS -Descending | Select Name,WS -First 10
```

Getting this:

[image: PowerShell]

Then task manager has this:

[image: Task Manager]

Are some other calculations I have to do? Could anyone explain?

PS: OS is in Portuguese.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, just realized what was happening. The dafault "Memory" column in Task Manager is actually representing the Private Working Set, not Working Set from Powershell, that represents private and shared memory with other process. Just enabled the "Memory - Working Set" column in Task Manager and it matches.

[image: Task Manager]

Obviously the values in Powershell are in bytes, need to calculate to Mb.

This page was also helpful:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-task-manager-memory-columns-mean#1TC=windows-7

Comment: To calculate in MB you can do something like this: `(Get-Process -Id 1234).WS/1MB` (Replace 1234 with the PID for the process you're interested in.) Also it seems there isn't a "Private Working Set" property in the objects returned by Get-Process.

Comment: Also, the Working Set in PowerShell is in KB by default (at least, on my system) - not bytes.

Comment: If you *really* want Private Working Set in PowerShell, it looks like someone's posted a solution over on [so]. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13878927/477682

Comment: The answer's URL is permanently gone (http error 301). I found the cached version: https://web.archive.org/web/20160623180320/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-task-manager-memory-columns-mean#1TC=windows-7 , but I am unable to find it on the new site.

Answer (score 2):

The (Shared) Working Set and the Private Working Set are two different things.

More info [A few words on memory usage or: working set vs. private working set](http://getgreenshot.org/2010/07/24/a-few-words-on-memory-usage-or-working-set-vs-private-working-set/).

To get the Private Working Set via Get-Process in PowerShell you can use "PrivateMemorySize":

`Get-process | Sort PrivateMemorySize -Descending | Select Name,PrivateMemorySize -First 10`