# In powershell, how can I get total private bytes used by a process?

Tags: memory, powershell

In powershell, how can I get total private bytes used by a process?

(I know process explorer has two columns, working set, and private bytes).

[I did find a command when I was researching but it didn't work and i've snipped it out of the question 'cos there were various issues with it that just make this question look more complicated than it is)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/802785/powershell-get-process-and-task-manager-discrepancy?

Comment: `Get-process | Sort PrivateMemorySize -Descending | Select Name,PrivateMemorySize -First 10`

Comment: You should be able to total them up yourself.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks that link is useful to get that line you give, and I have found a way to total it, though a total in excel is a bit different! Giving a small discrepancy as yet unexplained

Comment: thanks that link is useful to get that line you give, and I have found a way to total it

Answer (score 1):

David Postill mentions

```
Get-process | Sort PrivateMemorySize -Descending | Select Name,PrivateMemorySize -First 10
```

Which I see can be adapted to  this just for chrome.exe

```
PS C:\Users\harvey> Get-process chrome | Sort PrivateMemorySize -Descending | Select Name,PrivateMemorySize

    Name   PrivateMemorySize
    ----   -----------------
    chrome        1135521792
    chrome        1134342144
    chrome         718610432
    .....         ..........
```

The total of all those according to excel is

```
13851226112
```

and totalled with powershell is

```
PS C:\Users\user> (Get-Process chrome | Measure-Object PrivateMemorySize -sum).sum
13939982336
```

Note- (one can do PM instead of PrivateMemorySize, or WS for working set memory).

This `Get-process chrome | Select Name,WS,PM` shows both and one can sum in powershell or excel.

The sums differ a bit only because the timeframe the commands weren't run in a script, had they been run in a script then the totals would be the same. But there's a few seconds between running each.